# How do I get a Date from a week number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find all items created in a given week, and pass in a week number param. (created_at is a normal timestamp.)

Given a week number, what is the easiest way to find a date in that particular week? 
(Any date in the week will do, as I will use beginning_of_week and end_of_week in the scope.)

Comment: Presume you also have some year data (beyond the current system year), otherwise things will get interesting towards the end/start of each new year.

Comment: And you will need to say which week number definition you want to use (there are several around).

Comment: I think this application will do fine if I let the range be Date.today +/- 6 months, so I can get around the new year issue.

Comment: I take the week number from date.cweek.. haven't looked into if this is determined by my default locale. I'll test it, though. (This is a super local app, so I don't think it'll be an issue.)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can get Date objects representing the beginning and end of your week using the `commercial` method:

```
week = 41;

wkBegin = Date.commercial(2010, week, 1)
wkEnd = Date.commercial(2010, week, 7)
```

Now do your find:

```
  Item.find(:all, :conditions->:create_date=>wkBegin..wkEnd.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about Date.commercial

Comment: You will need wkEnd.end_of_day otherwise your range won't cover a whole week.
(wkEnd.to_time - wkBegin.to_time) / 1.day.seconds
  => 6.0

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean "a given week number in the current year", you can do the following:

```
2.weeks.since(Time.gm(Time.now.year))
=> Fri Jan 15 00:00:00 UTC 2010
```

Substitute `(week_number - 1)` for the `1` in the above, and you'll get a date in the desired week.