# Convert week number to a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Date from a week number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389395/how-do-i-get-a-date-from-a-week-number)
>   [Finding the date for a given week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574926/finding-the-date-for-a-given-week-number)

How would I convert a week number (%W) back to a certain date. For example converting week 20 to May 15, 2012.

Comment: Well you realize it could only be a *range* of dates to start with, right?

Comment: Is this for a particular year?  Week number starting from when?

Comment: Also the older: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389395/how-do-i-get-a-date-from-a-week-number

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check [Date#commercial](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial):

```
Date.commercial(2012, 20)
#=> Mon, 14 May 2012
```

Comment: Commercial may have some unexpected behaviour.. 


`(Date.commercial(2018, 52) + 7.day).strftime('%W') => 53`,
`Date.commercial(2018, 53) => ArgumentError: invalid date`,
`Date.commercial(2019, 1) =>  Mon, 31 Dec 2018`

Comment: Are you saying it may need some additional input validation to avoid invalid values giving disrupting behavior?  Seems reasonable to me to not allow greater than week 52.  Also the 2019 week 1/0 seems fine to me.  It's nice to highlight these edge cases, but I expected them.